# Postfix ignoring relay_recipient_maps?

Tags: email, postfix

I am trying to setup a mail relay running Postfix in the DMZ to forward all incoming mail to the internal LAN connected mail server.

I would like to be able to refuse incoming mail for non-existent users right at the gateway, which I assume is the best option.

The problem is, Postfix still accepts mail even for users not included in the users table.

My config:

```
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
local_recipient_maps =
local_transport = error:local delivery disabled
mydomain = ***
myhostname = merlin.***
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 10.7.0.0/16
myorigin = /etc/mailname
parent_domain_matches_subdomains = debug_peer_list smtpd_access_maps
relay_domains = $transport_maps
relay_recipient_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-relay_recipient_maps.cf
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport_maps
```

I have thorougly checked that the `relay_recipient_maps` work (using `postmap -q`). I am trying to send mail to `noone@***` with `swaks` from:

- The local machine (the mailserver itself)
- A host in the 10.7.11.x network

Both attempts succeed (Postfix relays the mail).

What's wrong?

**Edit:**

The log says (the "connection refused" error is irrelevant; the fact that Postfix relays for `noone@***` is the problem):

```
Aug  3 13:20:44 merlin postfix/smtp[10166]: CE7E2C6E: to=<noone@***>, relay=none, delay=1642, delays=1642/0.01/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to xaver.***[10.7.7.21]:25: Connection refused)
Aug  3 13:20:44 merlin postfix/smtp[10171]: connect to xaver.***[10.7.7.21]:25: Connection refused
```

Comment: Postfix accept the email because you 'have'  `permit_mynetworks` in your configuration

Comment: Thanks for reply; but after realizing my error and posting the answer below, everything works.

Answer (score 1):

After hours and reading that the lookup result is discarded for a minimum of eight times, I finally realized, that the stored funciton I use to check the existence of a user returns 0 when no matching entry is found. And that means to Postfix, well, that the user was found.